# c# number shaper for money amount like convert int 12333545 = 12,333,545

Tags: c#, asp.net, numbers, number-formatting

What is the easiest and fastest way of converting string or int to the money format

i mean like an integer = 21232221 when shaped = 21,232,221

c# 4.0 asp.net 4.0

thank you

the direct answer

```
    public static string NumberShaper(int irNumber)
{
    return (irNumber.ToString("N", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".00",""));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call `ToString` with the format string of choice.

For example, in your case:

```
int value = 21232221;

string result = value.ToString("N");
```

This will place 21,232,221 as the value in result.  To format as currency, use `"C"` (though this will add the currency specified, ie: $).  There are many options for format strings - for details, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: it is telling no string overload taking 1 argument

Answer (score 5):

Use formatting:

```
string formatted = 21232221.ToString("N0");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int money = 21232221;
var output = money.ToString("c");
```

Comment: it is telling no string overload taking 1 argument